# How To Add Event Listener To OverlayView?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, overlay-view

I am trying to create an OverlayView on google map as a custom marker.

I was able to create successfully  an OverlayView like the following.

http://plnkr.co/edit/4XDANE?p=preview

However, when I try to add event listeners to it, I got stuck.

I tried the followings with no luck.

```
    // ------------- Trying To Add DOM Event Listener ---
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(this.div, 'click', function(){
      alert(1); // NOT working
    })

    // ------------- Or, this ---
    this.div.addEventListener('click',function() {
      alert(1); // NOT working
    });
```

Anyone made this successfully?

----- update ----
As per @dr-molle suggests, the following accepts mouse click.

```
    //panes.overlayLayer.appendChild(div);   NOT THIS
    panes.overlayMouseTarget.appendChild(div);  // But, This

    // ------------- Trying To Add DOM Event Listener ---
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(this.div, 'click', function(){
      alert(1); // working
    })
```

Comment: Not sure, but are you trying to achieve something like this - http://humaan.com/custom-html-markers-google-maps/?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must use a different `pane` for the layer.

Currently you use `overlayLayer`, but only `overlayMouseTarget` and `floatPane` may receive DOM-events.

I would suggest to use `overlayMouseTarget` , your overlays would act like markers in this case(InfoWindows would be opened in front of the overlays)

Comment: `InfoWindows would be opened in front of the overlays`. I don't understand this though.

Comment: let's assume there are infoWindows that will be opened on the map(custom InfoWindows implemented by yourself or built-in infowindows, e.g. when a user clicks on a POI)...they would always cover your custom overlays.